# Disable a input field according a select field with CakePHP and JQuery

Tags: jquery, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to disable a input field according a select field using the JsHelper on CakePHP.

Anybody can help me?

I can populate a select field according another select field, but I can't disable a field.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the input using the .change() function on a select field.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9YXFJ/

```
$("#IDofSelect").change(function() {
    if (this.value == "1") {
        $("#IDofInput").prop("disabled", false);
    } else {
        $("#IDofInput").prop("disabled", true);
    }
});
```